# save data to sqlite from tweepy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, tweepy

i have this code to save data in cvs file now i want to save that data to sqlite or mysql but it should save like it is saving in cvs one by one record in database 
and one more question 
this data size will be 30-40MB per day which database i should use mysql or PostgresSql cause in the i have 1GB+ database every month
my idea is to make a website which have all stats of trends and i wanna use that with django

```
import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX')
auth.set_access_token('XXX-XXX', 'XXX')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                    q="google", 
                    since="2016-05-22", 
                    until="2016-05-23", 
                    lang="en").items():
    #Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLITE3 solution:

At first, create a DB, I used twitter2.db in this example. Basic connection to SQLITE3 and table creation:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\....\\twitter2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE tweeter(text VARCHAR, created_at DATETIME")
```

does the work:

```
import tweepy
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\....\\Desktop\\twitter2.db')
x = conn.cursor()
consumer_key="..."
consumer_secret=".."
access_token=".."
access_token_secret=".."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()


    def on_status(self, status):
            x.execute("""INSERT INTO tweeter (text,created_at) VALUES(?,?)""",
          (status.text, status.created_at))
            conn.commit()   

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=['google'])
```

closing the connection:

```
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I believe MySQL is ideal. It gives you security and it is best suited for web applications that you wish to build.